# xRegExp Replace expression

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace, xregexp

```
inputArray = ["z","d"];
inputArray = ["د","ذ"];
function trans(stri){
  inputArray.forEach((value, i) => {
    var next = i + 1;
    a1 = inputArray[i];
    a2 = outputArray[i];
    regex = new XRegExp(a1, "g"); 
    stri = XRegExp.replace(stri, regex, a2, ["all"])
    return stri;
});
}
console.log(trans("dzzd"))
```

I wanna translate from latin characters to arabic characters, how to use {{Arabic}}?, and I Very new to RegExp or even XRegExp, So how basically i do it? Also I'm very very sorry if im Lack of Experience..

Expected Output = "دذذد"

Comment: Looks okay, I think all you gotta do is have a variable outside the forEach, and replace it at the end of the loop (instead of returning - that just stops the loop after 1 run). And then after the loop ended, you just return that variable.

Comment: It said nothing to repeat

Comment: @Shai actually this looks okay. He's only using next inside, and it will always be the actual next value given `i` in the forEach callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all the replacements in one pass, making an alternation out of `inputArray` and using a replacement function to return the appropriate character from `outputArray` on a match:

```js
function trans(str, from, to) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp(`${from.join('|')}`, 'g'), function(m) {
    return to[from.indexOf(m)];
  });
}

inputArray = ["z", "d"];
outputArray = ["ذ", "د"];
console.log(trans('dzzd', inputArray, outputArray))
```

Note that if `from` might contain overlapping values (for example `ab` and `a`) you need to sort `from` and `to` by the length of the strings in `from` descending before using them. You can do that with this code:

```
// create an array of indexes
ids = Array.from({length : from.length}, (_, i) => i)
// sort the indexes by the length of the corresponding string in `from`
ids.sort((a, b) => from[b].length - from[a].length)
// now map from and to to the new order
from = from.map((_, i) => from[ids[i]])
to = to.map((_, i) => to[ids[i]])
```

This ensures that the regex always matches the longest sequence by preference (since it will come first in the alternation).

You could either insert into the `trans` function, for example:

```js
function trans(str, from, to) {
  ids = Array.from({ length: from.length }, (_, i) => i)
  ids.sort((a, b) => from[b].length - from[a].length)
  from = from.map((_, i) => from[ids[i]])
  to = to.map((_, i) => to[ids[i]])
  return str.replace(new RegExp(`${from.join('|')}`, 'g'), function(m) {
    return to[from.indexOf(m)];
  });
}

inputArray = ["zz", "d"];
outputArray = ["ذ", "د"];
console.log(trans('dzzd', inputArray, outputArray))
```

or use it on `inputArray` and `outputArray` before you call `trans`:

```js
function trans(str, from, to) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp(`${from.join('|')}`, 'g'), function(m) {
    return to[from.indexOf(m)];
  });
}

inputArray = ["zz", "d"];
outputArray = ["ذ", "د"];
ids = Array.from({ length: inputArray.length }, (_, i) => i)
ids.sort((a, b) => inputArray[b].length - inputArray[a].length)
inputArray = inputArray.map((_, i) => inputArray[ids[i]])
outputArray = outputArray.map((_, i) => outputArray[ids[i]])

console.log(trans('dzzd', inputArray, outputArray))
```

Comment: It works, but if it doesn't accept 2 or more characters input..

Comment: @user_425 do you mean translating from (for example) `'ab'` to `'c'`?

Comment: Yeah. But the "c" is Arabic letter

Comment: @user_425 please see my edit

Comment: Where must i put it? and Doesn't it will change the output because the outputArray doesnt change?

Comment: @user_425 please see my new edit. I've corrected the code and shown how to use it.

Comment: It say nothing to repeat.. also srry for late reply..

Comment: @user_425 that should not be possible with this code if the strings are all letters. Can you please give me the result of `console.log(\`${from.join('|')}\`)` inside the function?

Comment: Oh, I tried, yeah. But how if I wanna use symbols?

Comment: @user_425 it's not really reasonable to keep changing the question as you go. Instead, you should accept the answer you do get (assuming it works) and then ask a new question with the new requirements, referring back to the original as needed). Anyway, if you want to use symbols you will need to escape the strings in `inputArray` using a function like the one in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/9473764) with code like `inputArray = inputArray.map(escapeRegex)`